# How to disable call some public methods for all assemblies, but allow for somehow tagged assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have Entity assembly which describes objects, interfaces etc. This assembly has public methods. Other server's and client's assemblies has references to this Entity assembly. But some public methods must be closed for call from client's assemblies.

Now I changed access level from **public** to **internal** and listed serves's assembly names in AssemblyInfo.cs like this:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "ServerModule1" )]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "ServerModule2" )]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "ServerModule3" )]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "ServerModule4" )]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "ServerModule5" )]
...
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "ServerModule20" )]
```

But it's not good because after adding new Server assembly I have to add assembly name to Entity assembly and recompile.

Is there any ways to do it without modifying and recompiling Entity assembly?
May be Code Access Security or tagging Servers assemblies by security keys.

Comment: If a new assembly could simply say "I want access to those methods", would you really have accomplished anything? The only real way to do it is to allow it from the assembly that contains the methods.

Comment: New assembly can has security password for it for example.

Comment: But that password would be easily learned by just decompiling one such assembly. In any case, no, you can't do what you want.

Comment: I can copy methods names to another assembly (for example Entity.Server) as public methods then include to Entity assembly [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "Entity.Server" )]. Public methods from Entity.Server will call internal methods from Entity. Then share (include as reference) Entity.Server between all server assemblies. Is it better?

Comment: As for me it's ok to use InternalsVisibleTo, many controls libraries use such method to achieve modular assemblies, and to hide some implementation, so it's ok.

Comment: Unfortunately, get rid of recompiling Entity assembly important for us.

Comment: What about updating this assembly dynamically? For example Cecil can update your Entity assembly and append all needed InternalsVisibleTo, without recompilation, but the assembly still will be rewrited

Comment: I think dynamically updating is hard to understanding and to integrating to working process.